# How to generate debug symbols when building using mingw64

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64

I'm using `mingw64` (gcc 10.x) to build a few libraries (`libgsf` and its dependencies).
What should be set so the build will also generate debug symbols?
The compilation cmd is

```
MINGW_INSTALLS=mingw64 makepkg-mingw -sLf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate debug symbols you need to pass the `-g` flag to `gcc` org `g++`.

Comment: does it apply to `mingw64` compiler as well?

Comment: Yes it does. I use it all the time with MinGW-w64 in combination with GDB, both provided in the personal build at http://winlibs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Find or add next line into the PKGBUILD file:

```
options=('!strip' 'debug' 'staticlibs')
```

Or you can add this line into the global settings file `/etc/makepkg.conf` or `/etc/makepkg-mingw.etc`, depending what tpackages your are building: `MSYS` or `MINGW`:

```
OPTIONS=(!strip docs !libtool staticlibs emptydirs zipman purge debug !lto)
```

See comments from this file for details:

```
# Makepkg defaults: OPTIONS=(!strip docs libtool staticlibs emptydirs !zipman !purge !debug !lto)
#  A negated option will do the opposite of the comments below.
#
#-- strip:      Strip symbols from binaries/libraries
#-- docs:       Save doc directories specified by DOC_DIRS
#-- libtool:    Leave libtool (.la) files in packages
#-- staticlibs: Leave static library (.a) files in packages
#-- emptydirs:  Leave empty directories in packages
#-- zipman:     Compress manual (man and info) pages in MAN_DIRS with gzip
#-- purge:      Remove files specified by PURGE_TARGETS
#-- debug:      Add debugging flags as specified in DEBUG_* variables
#-- lto:        Add compile flags for building with link time optimization
```